# Migrating data from Oracle database to Pervasive .DAT files

Tags: oracle, migration

The requirement is to migrate some tables with data from a Oracle database server to Pervasive database's .DAT file. Then those .DAT files will be used by a Pervasive database server.

The restriction is that Oracle DB can not directly migrate to the Pervasive DB. It has to generate the .DAT files and then the new .DAT files will replace the old one for the Pervasive DB which will then use them for the new data.

I was trying this task with SSIS. Exporting the Oracle table to a delimited .txt file and then creating a .DAT file from that text file. I can export the data from Oracle to .txt but I am not finding any way to migrate .txt to Pervasive .DAT? Is this the right approach? If not then please help with my problem.

Comment: I take it you are using Pervasive SQL, and not their Transactional ISAM database?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to connect to the Pervasive database and execute SQL, you can use a tool like Oracle SQLDeveloper (http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) to export your data as SQL Inserts and then run those against  your Pervasive database.